# PHPmyadmin batch update with != condition

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to edit all values in term_taxonomy_id that are NOT 25 to 4

```
 UPDATE `iplusuco_wp2`.`wp_term_relationships`
 SET `term_taxonomy_id` =  4
 WHERE `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` !=25
```

but I got this error, is there any way to fix this query? Thanks!

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '151-4' for key 'PRIMARY'

[phpmyadmin table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNcfj.png)

EDIT: Added screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Try `<>` instead of `!=`.

In case of `NULL` values you may want to use `<=>` [NULL-safe equal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you comparing this once as a string and once as a number? That doesn't make sense.. Try this

```
UPDATE  `iplusuco_wp2`.`wp_term_relationships`
 SET  `term_taxonomy_id` =  4
where `wp_term_relationships`.`term_taxonomy_id` !=25
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I got this error instead: #1062 - Duplicate entry '151-4' for key 'PRIMARY'